# How to access files which is stored in custom folder of internal storage using external app?

Tags: android, file, permissions

I have a zip file. I am unzipping it to internal storage. When unzipping each file, I am keeping the same folder structure. After unzipping all levels, I want to display the files using appropriate third party apps like adobe reader etc.

I can unzipping and creating files with same folder structure. But the problem is the files could not be displayed through external app, because of permission. I couldn't set WORLD_READABLE PERMISSION, because the files are storing in custom folders. I applied setReadable also. But no hope.

How can I show files, or how to get permission to files?

Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks
Jomia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to serve up the files from your app's internal storage using a `ContentProvider`.

Or, put the files on external storage, instead of internal storage.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried with FilProvider. But getting NullPoinerException on at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile.  Could you please share the link of any good example for FileProvider?

Comment: @Jomia: Off the cuff, my guess is that `getUriForFile()` cannot determine how your file is supposed to be served. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) is mostly a basic `FileProvider` example, though mine ties in a `LegacyCompatCursorWrapper` that tries to help improve compatibility with older clients.